# nhibernate : how to query collection inside parent entity

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following method. This works fine if i remove the following line

```
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Product.IsPopItem", true))
```

The error message is

**could not resolve property: Product.IsPopItem of: EStore.Domain.Model.ProductCategory**

I'm confident the "Product.IsPopItem" is mapped correctly as i can call this property. Do i need to add a few criteria.

```
 public ICollection<ProductCategory> FindByCompanyIdAndCategoryIdAndIsPop(int companyId, int id)
    {
        var products = _session
            .CreateCriteria(typeof(ProductCategory))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CompanyId", companyId))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CategoryId", id))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Product.IsPopItem", true))
            .List<ProductCategory>();
        return products;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you need to add an .CreateAleas

```
 .CreateAlias("Product", "product", JoinType.InnerJoin)
```

please change JoinType to your need, and use "product" alias instead of property name "Product"

so final should be something like:

```
.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProductCategory))
        .CreateAlias("Product", "product", JoinType.InnerJoin)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CompanyId", companyId))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CategoryId", id))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("product.IsPopItem", true))
        .List<ProductCategory>());
        return products;
```

Comment: beat me to it just as I started to type :)

Comment: :) sorry, just helped a colleague with the same problem